# R - where can vectorize happen?

Tags: r

So clearly one way to vectorize a function is WITHIN the function - either explicitly iterate over inputs or utilize other functions that have been vectorized.  Is there a way to mark or tag a function as being/treated as vectorized so that the iteration is managed by the R platform?  The analogy would be attributes in c# or annotations in Java.  I tell R that this function should be treated as vectorized and it feeds that input one at a time into the function, constructing the vector output?  Or am I just thinking about this whole thing incorrectly?

Comment: Probably incorrectly. You don't tell R that a function is vectorised; this arises from how you write your function and what R functionality you use in it. In R, I don't think iterating over inputs is really vectorised in the R-sense - even with the `apply()` family you are just hiding the loop (although there are exceptions - before I get shouted at :-).

Comment: There are some useful and interesting observations in chapter 3 of the R inferno: 
http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S//Spoetry/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @Andrie - great resource!  looking forward to reading this PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Vectorize function (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/mapply.html), to make the function take vectors.

But here it just uses the mapply function to do the vectorization. As Gavin said, you are just hiding the loop.